# Understand FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and onNewIntent

Tags: android

My Android application consists of 2 activities: A and B with different task affinities. From activity A, I start activity B with flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. Similarly, from activity B, I use the same intent flag to start activity A. Although activity A still exists, onCreate method is called instead of onNewIntent. Also, pressing the back button takes me to the home screen. How can I understand this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

`onNewIntent` only works with Activities with `singleTop` launch mode, which means that if that activity is on top, don't launch a new one instead deliver this intent to it inside `onNewIntent`. This doesn't take effect if activity is not on top of the stack.

From Docs:

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
If set, this activity will become the start of a new task on this history stack.
```

So the new launched activity has no previous activity in this newly created task and this pressing back takes you to home screen.

If you want your activities to have only a single instance throughout your App then you can use `singleTask` in the manifest. From Docs:

```
The system creates a new task and instantiates the activity at the
root of the new task. However, if an instance of the activity already
exists in a separate task, the system routes the intent to the existing
instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than
creating a new instance. Only one instance of the activity can exist at a time.
```

Comment: @Souabh  i agree to the fact that no new instance of the activity is created if it exists. But i am confused how the intent will be delivered when the target activity(whom the intent is sent ) is below some other activity?